# How can I list all the packages that come on a default snap?

Tags: snap

I want to get a list of all packages installed by default in a snap. When trying to find dependencies of a program to create a snap I want to know if certain packages are or are not already in the snap core. It would be nice if this could be done from command line. Ideally I should get a list of installed packages on a default snap but also on a particular snap so I could grep it.

Answer (score 0):

You can often find the packages that a snap bundles as dependencies by going to /snap/yourSnapName/current/snap/snapcraft.yaml.in or /snap/yourSnapName/current/snap/snapcraft.yaml. Or you can try and find the `snapcraft.yaml` in a GitHub repo online.

That's not a complete answer for your use-case, I think a manifest might be what you're looking for? [That feature has not yet been developed](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/use-a-separate-manifest-file-or-save-everything-in-snap-snapcraft-yaml/1152).

Comment: I was trying to create a snap, so I don't have a yaml file. I was trying to avoid adding packages to the yaml that are already in the core.